# How to get my images in my /res folder dynamically

Tags: android, image, view

I am trying to get images out of my /res folder dynamically and I am just confused on the next part.  I looked around StackOverflow and saw this example which is what I needed to start off with:

```
String fName = "android.resource://j.l.library11/drawable/" + itemName;
```

I thought though that since its in my /res folder it would be:

```
String fName = "android.resource://j.l.library11/drawable/res/" + itemName;
```

Which 1 of these 2 would be correct?

Also, I am just confused on what my next few steps would be to get to the point where I can set my ImageView (iView) with the image from my /res folder (itemName).  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is:

```
File file = new File(fName);
```

and then get the hash code

```
int itemHashCode = file.HashCode()
```

and then use that as

```
iView.setImageResource(itemHashCode).
```

Would that work or does anyone know the correct solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images placed in res/drawable are automatically compiled by AAPT to integer mappings inside of your R.java class. You can set the image on an ImageView using:

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nameOfYourImage);
```

**EDIT:** I'm not clear on why you'd want to do what you're doing, but setting the resource of an ImageView with the hashcode of your image will cause a ResourceNotFoundException.

**EDIT:** If you're trying to be able to set the image dynamically based on an association with some data from a database, then take advantage of the fact that you have compiled drawables by saving the int of of your R.drawable.imagename in a new integer column in your DB. Then you can simply set the image like `setImageResource(intFromDB)`. If you aren't setting up the DB in code and, therefore, don't have access to the compiled R.drawable, an alternative is something like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String mDrawableName = "image_name";
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resourceId);
icon.setImageDrawable(drawable );
```

Or even shorter, this may work:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("mypackagename:drawable/imageName", null, null);
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: This doesn't work to how I need it though.

myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nameOfYourImage);

The "nameOfYourImage" is what is going to be dynamic and when I place the string that is passed into my method (itemName) it tells me that I cant have strings inside of setImageResource().  Such as setImageResource(R.drawable. + "itemName").

Comment: See my edit. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: That's correct, because the method setImageResource expects an int and that int has to be one of the ints from R.drawable

Comment: So if I had a method that had a String parameter ( the item name) how would I go about using that item name to find the item image in my /res folder and then set it to my ImageView I guess is what I am trying to say.

Comment: You're not explaining what this method is..."If I had a method"... Why do you have a such a method and why can't you use the normal R.drawable.myImage?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16948/discussion-between-joeyl-and-luxurymode)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with reflection:

```
Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
for(Field field:fields){
    try {
            imageView.setImageResource(field.getInt(null));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```